# How to enable roving tabIndex in React?

Tags: reactjs, tabindex

I have a list of radio button groups I am rendering through a loop in a React class. I want to be able to tab to each group and select through the arrow keys. Here's my loop code:

```
{questions.map((question, index) =>
    <div key={question.id}>
        <label>{question.text}</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name={question.name} value="Completely Agree" />
            <div>Completely Agree</div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name={question.name} value="Agree" />
            <div >Agree</div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name={question.name} value="Somewhat Agree" />
            <div >Somewhat Agree</div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name={question.name} value="Somewhat Disagree" />
            <div >Somewhat Disagree</div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name={question.name} value="Disagree" />
            <div >Disagree</div>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name={question.name} value="Completely Disagree" />
            <div>Completely Disagree</div>
        </label>
    </div>
)}
```

I tried to use the [react-roving-tabindex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-roving-tabindex) but I can't seem to understand how to translate the example they're demonstrating through typescript. I looked into the [Creating an accessible tab component with React](https://medium.com/@andreasmcd/creating-an-accessible-tab-component-with-react-24ed30fde86a) article but I'm not sure using ID's all over the place is a good idea. Is there a way React adheres to a simpler way of enabling roving tabIndexes?

Comment: Are you trying to render your example as Tabs instead of radio?

Comment: No. I'm trying to render as radio. I forgot to mention that I want to tab through the wrapping labels, with the radio buttons hidden. Apologies for not mentioning that. I'm hiding the checkboxes and showing them as checked through the CSS properties applied in the divs inside the labels. So, I suppose I'd want to tab through the labels.